# OnBackPressed() brings back incorrect activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Within my Main_Activity, I have a Button which when OnClicked opens the new Game_Activity, within the OnCreate of my Game_Activity I have:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_true_false);
    level1GameInstructions = new Level1GameInstructions();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.game_activity, instructions).commit();
}
```

Which opens a Fragment, then within the Fragment class when a Button is clicked i want to close the current Fragment open so I have done this:

```
View.OnClickListener playBtnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
};
```

However, for some reason this returns the Main_Activity rather than the Game_Activity. Does anyone know why?

Comment: `getActivity().onBackPressed()` is just like `getActivity().finish()` in your case. Never do it that way

Comment: Check what `android:parentActivityName` is set to in manifest file.

Comment: @RomanSamoylenko So what would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: In Android, there is no out-of-the-box support for pressing back in a fragment. So when you write `getActivity().onBackPressed()` it is handled by the activity, which in turn takes the user back to the previous activity (unless you override `onBackPressed`  in the activity. I have to say I'm not sure what you are trying to do. It seems like GameActivity is just a holder for Level1GameInstructions, so what exactly do you want to display when the user hits that button?

Answer (score 0):

Be glad to use these two methods instead of your code:

```
public void removeFragment(@NonNull String tag) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();
}

public void replaceFragment(@IdRes int containerId, Fragment fragment, @Nullable String tag) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment, tag).commit();
}
```

Just replace the needed fragment with some tag, and remove it by that tag.